# Django Python : JSONDecodeError at /Flashcard/ Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

When the user submits this form I want to save the rgb color code as a variable to be stored on the back end (using django), so whenever the card is loaded (the colour picked on this page) will be loaded. I asked GPT, which suggested using ajax (I've never used it before).

This is a snippet from my js :

```
 function updateSetColor(color) {
            var formatted_color = JSON.stringify(color)
            console.log(formatted_color);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Flashcard/",
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ color: formatted_color }),
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log("Error updating color");
                    },
                    cache: false,
                });
        }
```

This is a snippet from my view that uses the color variable sent from the data :

```
 if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid() and request.accepts('main/Flashcard.html'):
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        color = data.get('color')
# code continues
```